# detect prepared batch statements in ODBC

Tags: sql, odbc

Is there a way in ODBC to detect if a statement that has been prepared is an [explicit batch statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712553%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), *without* executing it or trying to parse it myself? More precisely, is this information available after calling `SQLPrepare` but before calling `SQLExecute`? (It's easy to tell *after* execution is easy: it's a batch statement if `SQLMoreResults` returns `SQL_SUCCESS` or `SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO`.)